# How to Remove non-duplicate records in Excel 2016

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to know how I can delete unique/non-duplicate records from an Excel
file which is about 70 megabytes in size.

Comment: You could use the Advanced Filter, with a formula criteria to retain only the duplicate records.

Comment: Thanks You for Your reply it is much appreciated. But can you give me step by step guide on how to do so as i don't have much experience in this field.

Comment: You've not provided sufficient information for that sort of thing.  I suggest you carefully read the Help topic for the Advanced Filter, especially as regards to using a formula; use a formula that returns `True` for the duplicate records that you want to keep (eg probably a `COUNTIF` or `SUMPRODUCT`; and then use that as the filter criteria.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose the column and in the MS Excel field "Data" you can find the button "delete duplicates" with the icon [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFEvU.png)

Try to export the sheet to Google docs and work with them. In section "Data" you can find ico [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxkwo.png) "clearence data" and find in the sub-menu  Delete duplicates. After clic on them you can choose many option (from row, from sheet, from whole document) and after finishing work with file you can export back to the MS file.

Also, you can find some external services that can work with the MS Excel files for example: https://products.aspose.com/ or https://www.devexpress.com/ or https://products.groupdocs.com/ But in that type of service you need to know .net or Java or C++ or C#

Answer (score 0):

From the article
[How to color duplicate values or duplicate rows in Excel?](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3080-excel-color-duplicates.html),
to color duplicate values:

1. Select the data range you want to color the duplicate values, then click *Home > Conditional Formatting > Highlight Cells Rules > Duplicate Values*.
2. In the dialog, select the color for highlighting duplicates
3. Click OK.

Once you have marked the duplicate rows by color, you may then filter
the rows by color, and so delete the duplicated or non-duplicated rows:

1. Select the column
2. Click the arrow on the right in the heading for the column
3. In the drop down, click *Filter by Color*, and select the color that
   you used
4. Now that only these rows are displayed, you may select and delete
   them, or save them somewhere else and delete the others.

For another method of removing duplicates, the Office article
[Find and remove duplicates](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/find-and-remove-duplicates-00e35bea-b46a-4d5d-b28e-66a552dc138d)
advises to click *Data > Remove Duplicates*, and then under Columns, check or
uncheck the columns where you want to remove duplicates.

Comment: Thank You For your answer.I dont want to color duplicate rows and columns i just want to know how to remove non-duplicates in and excel spreadsheet!!!!

Comment: You can filter by color and manipulate the filtered rows. See above.